# Plot not plotting entire range of function

Tags: plotting

I have a simple function that I want to plot. I am using Mathematica 8 on a windows machine.

I type the following code:

```
Plot[100*0.5^n,{n,0,20}];
```

And the resulting graph only goes to 25 on the y not 100 like it should. Should I be telling Mathematica to do so?

Comment: have you looked at `PlotRange` in the documentation?

Comment: I have not, I will do so. Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First the reason: Mathematica has to try to display the *interesting* part of the function for you. Since the function is on a long range very small, it assumes you maybe want a smaller range. Such an approach works most of the times very well but not always.

You have the chance to adjust the range of the plotting by using the `PlotRange` option:

```
Plot[100*0.5^n, {n, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Thank you much, I had an inkling that Mathematica was trying to show me what it thought I wanted, y I no let program tell me what's best?

Answer (score 4):

Like *halirutan* says you can use `PlotRange -> All` to see the full graph over the given input range. Note that yo can also use `PlotRange` to select part of the output range:

```
Plot[100*0.5^n, {n, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}]
```

If you use `PlotRange` with two ranges the first one is the range on your x-axis, and overrides the range you chose for the `Plot`:

```
Plot[100*0.5^n, {n, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {{5, 10}, {0, 10}}]
```

Comment: That makes for an interesting use of `PlotRange` now I know specifically how to zoom in on parts of the `Range` that I might desire.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator - yes, that was the point of my answer. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to plot the `Log` of your function; this will show the interesting feature :

```
LogPlot[100*0.5^n, {n, 0, 20}]
```

[image: LogPlot]

Comment: This does indeed show an interesting feature, I did not even think to plot the log of it.