# White regions in DensityPlot?

Tags: plotting, color, faq

When I try to supply my own `ColorFunction` Mathematica seems to partially ignore it, and the white color "burns through" if the function is too "sharp":

```
mycf[z_] := RGBColor[z, 0, 0]

GraphicsRow[
  {DensityPlot[(Sin[x] Sin[y])^4, {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi},
    ColorFunction -> mycf, ColorFunctionScaling -> False],
   DensityPlot[(Sin[x] Sin[y])^5, {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, 
    ColorFunction -> mycf, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]}
]
```

[image: density plots]

Comment: Try `PlotRange -> All`.

Comment: A version of: [(8390)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8390/121)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`DensityPlot[]` was automatically cutting off your function at the peak. To fix this, add the option `PlotRange -> All`:

```
DensityPlot[(Sin[x] Sin[y])^5, {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, 
            ColorFunction -> mycf, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: correct density plot]

---

**Why does *Mathematica* cut off values at all?**

With the default setting of `PlotRange -> Automatic`, *Mathematica* will often choose not to show the highest or lowest values (outliers) in an attempt to present a useful plot. The decisions it makes are not perfect, but on average are better than a default of `PlotRange -> All` would be. Consider for example the following situation:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Why community wiki?

Comment: @Rahul Because he can :)