# Density map strange mapping of color

Tags: plotting, color

I tried to convince *Mathematica* 8 to plot a density map of a function:

$$f(x,y) = \frac{2(x^2 - y^2)-1}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}$$

with color scheme called "TemperatureMap". At $x = \pm 1$, $y = 0$ it's completely correct, but at $y = \pm 1$, $x = 0$, it shows white color, where, in fact, it should be blue. I'm only interested in the region $x^2 + y^2 > 1$, so I added the command: `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` and manually rescaled my function to take values only between 0 and 1:

$$g(x,y) = \frac14 (3+f(x,y))$$

as I know where the maxima and minima occur in the region I'm interested in. The plot is even more strange, leaving almost no blue and, of course, at $x = 0, y = \pm 1$ it's white.

Whole input I used was (PlotPoints so I can get higher quality plot, Exclusions so I can see where's the boundary of region I'm interested in):

```
DensityPlot[(3 + 2*(x^2 - y^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^2 - 1/(x^2 + y^2)^2)/
  4, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Exclusions -> {x^2 + y^2 == 1}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I expected a similar density map to the second image on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow_around_a_circular_cylinder). Instead the space approximately $(y/1.2)^2 + x^2 < 1$ is white. The region left of the white part is not exactly an ellipse, it looks like a ladyfinger. Where did I make a mistake?

I tried to plot a constant function 0 and 1 while `ColorFunctionScaling` being false and it correctly showed whole plot blue and red respectively. I don't have the slightest clue what went wrong.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: The white region has very high values so it's clipped.  You can adjust the clipping with `PlotRange`.  `PlotRange -> All` clips nothing, but it's not useful here.  `PlotRange -> m {-1,1}` clips below `-m` and above `m`.

Comment: Wow, man, thanks, that's EXACTLY what needed to be done. Now it works like a charm. I still don't know how come it drawn the wrong for $g(x,y) = 1$ (I tried to produce contourplot with the similar effect), but now with this plotrange thing it works.

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Mathematica how you want clipping handled.

```
f[x_, y_] = 2*(x^2 - y^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^2 -
    1/(x^2 + y^2)^2 // Simplify;

Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
 ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]

```
DensityPlot[f[x, y],
 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
 ClippingStyle -> Darker[Blue]]
```

[image]

From the example to which you linked, you presumably want a `Disk` rather than a circle for the region x^2 + y^2 < 1

```
DensityPlot[f[x, y],
 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 ClippingStyle -> Darker[Blue],
 Epilog -> {Gray, Disk[]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Bob Hanlon: thanks, that helped a lot, it's exactly what I wanted to achieve. Is there a similar way to specify how long vector should be in vectorplot? Due to few bad vectors near the origin which are too long because of singularity at origin no other vectors show. On the one hand I like to elminate those vectors at the origin, on the other hand I want it to keep the scale for other ones.

Comment: @user16320 - If you have a question about VectorPlot ask another question with an appropriate subject line. Provide initial code that demonstrates issue.