# Densityplot gives unexpected result

Tags: plotting, color

I want to plot the density of this function:

```
Knot := {0, 0, 0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1, 1, 1};
f[xi_, eta_] := BSplineBasis[{2, Knot}, 3, xi]*BSplineBasis[{2, Knot}, 3, eta];
```

The range of this function is nicely contained in [0, 1], but its maximum is somewhere around 1/2. I want a linear color map that maps 0 to white and 1 to red - so I don't want to rescale the colors:

```
DensityPlot[f[xi, eta], {xi, 0, 1}, {eta, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> Function[z, RGBColor[1, 1 - z, 1 - z]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

This gives a weird result:

[image: density plot]

I would expect the density plot to be smooth. Indeed, the 3d plot is smooth - and the color function behaves as I would expect:

```
Plot3D[f[xi, eta], {xi, 0, 1}, {eta, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RGBColor[1, 1 - z, 1 - z]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: 3d plot]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are right, I was sloppy. I fixed this in the question (to the best of my knowledge) - but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: As Kuba says, if you had checked the docs for `DensityPlot[]` (under "Details and Options", 14th bullet), you'd have done `DensityPlot[f[xi, eta], {xi, 0, 1}, {eta, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> Function[{z}, RGBColor[1, 1 - z, 1 - z]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> All]`.

Comment: Have you seen [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14260/white-regions-in-densityplot-is-this-a-bug-with-colorfunctionscaling)?

Comment: @aardvark No, but I wish I had found it :)

Comment: @J.M. I am not very familiar with Mathematica. I did spend about an hour googling, and checking various docs including that for DensityPlot. I admit that it is stupid that I missed this in hindsight. I have a deadline for my thesis coming up, and know that more experienced people like you would probably see my mistake very quickly. This being said: I'll happily accept if you make that an answer, even if you include the sassy tone ;)

Comment: @aardvark, thanks for finding it; I was having a bit of trouble remembering where I wrote that. :D