# Why do I always have a grey corner on my plot?

Tags: plotting

I have encountered a very wired plotting issue:

I had a script to plot 6 triangles together in one graph as below (first figure). However, as you could see there are always two grey parts in the corner that come from nowhere. When I simply plot these two triangles, they look perfect as in the second & third figure.

Could anybody tell me what mistake I have made? Thanks so much in advance!

Yi

[image]

[image]

Comment: Clipping. Show a MWE (i.e. code that produces the problem) for more advice.  Or look it up in the documentation for `Plot` and post your own answer.

Comment: Add `PlotRange->All` to each of your plots, once they are calculated you can't adjust it above what was set.

Comment: closely related: [14260](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14260/5478)