# Restore the figure in the PRL paper

Tags: plotting

the paper from this https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.01420v2.pdf

I finished the first few pictures of the paper，and now I have this unwieldy graph。

[image]

This graph is actually a graph of conformal transformations

$$
W=z+\frac{1}{z}
$$

form maping ,we get get new `x'` and `y'`,like this

$$
x^{\prime}+i y^{\prime}=(x+i y)+\frac{1}{(x+i y)}
$$

I take the real and imaginary parts of this

$$
\begin{aligned}
&x^{\prime}=\operatorname{Re}\left[x+i y+\frac{1}{(x+i y)}\right] \\
&y^{\prime}=\operatorname{Im}\left[x+i y+\frac{1}{(x+i y)}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

and do this

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left(\nabla x^{\prime}\right)^{2}=\left(\frac{\partial x^{\prime}}{\partial x}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial x^{\prime}}{\partial y}\right)^{2} \\
&\left(\nabla y^{\prime}\right)^{2}=\left(\frac{\partial y^{\prime}}{\partial x}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial y^{\prime}}{\partial y}\right)^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Finally, I define the function I want：

$$
\begin{gathered}
n^{2}(x, y)=\frac{n_{0}}{2}\left[\left(\nabla x^{\prime}\right)^{2}+\left(\nabla y^{\prime}\right)^{2}\right] \\
n_{0}=3.1
\end{gathered}
$$

I have do some work by Wolfram

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
(*=== constant ===*)
n0 = 3.1;

(*===define maping ===*)

confun[x_, y_] := x + I y + 1/(x + I y);
comconfun = 
  Assuming[x \[Element] Reals && y \[Element] Reals, 
   ComplexExpand@confun[x, y]];

(*=== Re and Im ===*)
reconfun = x + x/(x^2 + y^2);
imconfun = y - y/(x^2 + y^2);
(*=== calculate delta(x') and delta(y')===*)

deltaXY = 
  Plus @@ Map[Power[#, 2] &, Grad[{reconfun, imconfun}, {x, y}]] // 
   Simplify;

(*=== define I want function u(x,y) ===*)

n[x_, y_] := n0^2/2*(deltaXY[[1]] + deltaXY[[2]]*I);

(*=== plot Re[function] ===*)
recontour = 
 DensityPlot[n0^2/2*deltaXY[[1]],
  {x, -5, 5},
  {y, -5, 5},
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  PlotLegends -> Automatic
  ]
```

get this:

[image]

Comparing the two pictures, I found a big difference. Now I don't know how to deal with it

[image]

[image]

(===================  upgrate   ==========================)

by @rhermans suggest

I change some

```mathematica
(*=== plot Re[function] ===*)

disk = Graphics[{Black, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}];

recontour = DensityPlot[n0^2/2*deltaXY[[1]],
  {x, -5, 5},
  {y, -5, 5},
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Norm[{x, y}] > 1],
  PlotRange -> {0, 6},
  ClippingStyle -> {RGBColor["#e93424"]},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic
  ]
Show[recontour, disk]
```

[image]

"Red" here is not gradient

Comment: Then, what is the question?

Comment: @rhermans Comparing the two pictures, I found a big difference. Now I don't know how to deal with it

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Which of the many differences do you want to fix? Axis, fonts, colours, domain, range?

Comment: @rhermans The color doesn't really matter, what matters is that my graph has "hollow holes" (it's white)

Comment: The white patch is due to the cutoff being done by `DensityPlot[]`; see e.g. [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14260).

Comment: @J.M. I use `PlotRange -> All` ,the plot is very strange

Comment: Define the *cloaked region* using `RegionFunction-> Function[{x,y},Norm[{x,y}]>1]` also your function give different numbers, the white regions are points where your functions is clipped because it's out of range (See `ClippingStyle` and set `PlotRange->{0,6}` ).

Comment: @rhermans by your answer，I've changed a bit through your advice, but it's still not perfect

Comment: Are you sure that the function (`n0^2/2*deltaXY[[1]]`) is correct?  I say that because the value is 3 where the bright yellow is on the original figure (along the diagonals).  However, on your last figure given, the diagonals have a value between 4 and 5 (with something closer to 4.8 if one uses `ContourPlot` with 30 contours).  And the black disk has a radius around 2.4 and not 1 as your last figure indicates.  Finally, please be more specific than "but it's still not perfect".

Comment: @JimB I am sure it is right ，form the paper "Whereas the first term on the right-hand side of the above equation, $ \left(n_{0}^{2} / 2\right)\left[\left(\nabla x^{\prime}\right)^{2}+\left(\nabla y^{\prime}\right)^{2}\right] $ is the conformal part"

Comment: In the original picture,what is the value `λ` in  `x/λ` and `y/λ`?

Comment: @cvgmt I think you solved it with that comment.  I measured the radius of the black disk to be close to 2.4 (using some digitizer software).   And now looking at the article there is the following in the Figure 1 caption:  "Real-valued refractive index distribution of the conformal Zhukovsky cloak, reaching values of n = 0 at x = ±2.4λ".

Comment: @cvgmt I think $\lambda$ can get 1,Makes no difference to the results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the paper draw such figure by the following approach.

**Edit**

The correct `n[x,y]` still need to be study.

```
n0 = 3.1;
w = Block[{z = x + I*y}, ComplexExpand@ReIm[z + 1/z]];
f[x_, y_] = 
 Norm[Grad[w, {x, y}], "Frobenius"] /. Abs -> Identity // Simplify
n[x_, y_] = n0/Sqrt[2] f[x, y]

recontour = 
  DensityPlot[n[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
   ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 80, 
   MaxRecursion -> 4];
Show[recontour, Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, 2.14]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The following sequence of commands seems to come close to duplicating that figure:

```
n0 = 3.1;
reconfun = x + x/(x^2 + y^2);
imconfun = y - y/(x^2 + y^2);
g = Sqrt[(n0^2/2) Plus @@ Map[Power[#, 2] &, Grad[{reconfun, imconfun}, {x, y}]] // Total];

Show[DensityPlot[g, {x, -6/2.4, 6/2.4}, {y, -6/2.4, 6/2.4}, 
  PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 6.2}}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Darker[Blue], Cyan, Yellow, Orange, Darker[Red, 0.5]}, #] &),
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{{-5/2.4, 5}, 0, {5/2.4, -5}}, None}, {{{-5/2.4, -5}, 0, {5/2.4, 5}}, None}},
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 24], 
  FrameLabel -> {{Style["y/λ", 24, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", Italic],        None}, 
    {Style["x/λ", 24, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", Italic], 
     Style["n(x,y)", 24, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", Italic]}}],
 Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]]
```

[image: Figure 2a]

Comment: That's a good color mix

Comment: I change `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic,Ticks->{0,3,6}]` ，“0” not find？

Comment: @我心永恒 and Jim: I implemented the `jet` colormap [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9321152), if you really want to reproduce the original coloration. Also, here's how to get `g` in one line: `n0 Sqrt[Simplify[# . # &[Flatten[D[ComplexExpand[ReIm[(x + I y) + 1/(x + I y)], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], {{x, y}}]]]/2]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks to U