Removing white regions from density plot
I am trying to use a density plot to show the value of a function, but I get white regions that I don't know how to get rid of. I have used several questions and answers in this website and have improved this now, but the issue is not completely solved. Could someone please help me with this?
  a[GG_, bb_, Pnn_] := (
  1 - Pnn (EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, GG]))/(-1 + 
   bb  Pnn (EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, GG/bb]));
    s = 0.01;
Pnn = 92/100;
h[GG_, bb_, s_, Pnn_] := 
  GG (1 - E^(-(s/GG)) ) h00 ((1 + a[GG, bb, Pnn])/(
    a[GG, bb, Pnn]  bb - a[GG, bb, Pnn]  bb  E^(-(s/bb)) + 1 - (
     E^-s)  ));
KK[GG_, bb_, s_, Pnn_] := (Pnn  \[Pi])/
   2  (h00/  h[GG, bb, s, Pnn] - (a[GG, bb, Pnn]  bb + 1 )/(
     GG (1 + a[GG, bb, Pnn]) ));
trans[x_] = E^x/(1 + E^x);
inverse[y_] = Log[y/(1 - y)];
With[{ticks = 18}, 
 DensityPlot[
   trans[KK[GG, bb, 2/100, 92/100]], {bb, 1/100, 4}, {GG, 2, 4}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   PlotRange -> All] /. 
  BarLegend[{a_, b_}, c___] :> 
   BarLegend[{a, b}, 
    Ticks -> 
     N[{#, Quiet[
          inverse[#]]} & /@ (Range @@ 
           Append[#, -Subtract @@ #/(ticks - 1)] &[
         SetPrecision[b, \[Infinity]]]), 3], c]]

I also tried
    DensityPlot[
 LogisticSigmoid[Re[KK[GG, bb, 2/100, 92/100]]], {bb, 1/100, 4}, {GG, 
  2, 4}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> All]

But there is no success.

Can you provide the definition of $a$, as in a[GG, bb, Pnn]

@LouisB I have added it to the question now. Thanks for pointing out

See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14260/white-regions-in-densityplot?rq=1

Try Exclusions -> None. If your function has an infinite range, you can't get rid of the white in any other way AFAIR. Also adding MaxRecursion -> 4 takes only slightly longer, but looks much better and gets $-\infty$ into the range as well. -- Tips: Including some of these details would have been helpful. So would including the graphics that were produced. You want to attract as many people as you can to try out your code. Maybe because it's the weekend the response has been slow, but there are a lot of people on this site who could have figured this out.

In the Mathematica cloud version 14.1.0, all three options Exclusions->None, PlotPoints->100 and PlotRange->All were required.
ClearAll["Global`*"]

a[GG_, bb_, Pnn_] := (1 - Pnn (EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, GG]))/(-1 + 
   bb  Pnn (EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, GG/bb]));

s = 0.01;
Pnn = 92/100;
h[GG_, bb_, s_, Pnn_] := GG (1 - E^(-(s/GG)) ) h00 ((1 + 
    a[GG, bb, Pnn])/(a[GG, bb, Pnn]  bb - 
    a[GG, bb, Pnn]  bb  E^(-(s/bb)) + 1 - (E^-s)) );
KK[GG_, bb_, s_, Pnn_] := (Pnn  \[Pi])/
   2  (h00/  h[GG, bb, s, Pnn] - (a[GG, bb, Pnn]  bb + 1 )/(
     GG (1 + a[GG, bb, Pnn]) ));
trans[x_] = E^x/(1 + E^x);
inverse[y_] = Log[y/(1 - y)];

 DensityPlot[
   trans[KK[GG, bb, 2/100, 92/100]], {bb, 1/100, 4}, {GG, 2, 4}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Exclusions -> None,
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All] 



In such a case replace
 Inactive[Plot][expr_,domain__List, options___] -> Table[expr,domain] 

and look for undefined symbols, here the function a[] is nonmumeric.

Could you please explain more about how to apply this to my code? I have added the definition of a[]

I use    cc=Inactive[DensityPlot][.....] to control output for undefined symbols. Then do Activated[cc] to see the graphics output. It's ok now. For numeric of non reals copy the arguments of Density plot including the domain but without options and paste it into the Table[...]. The output must be numbers only evaluted at the 4 boundary points
